# Rewording a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How else can I reword the following

> There are few better ways

Here is the sentence I am using this in

> There are few better ways to ring in the new year than with a bigger monthly budget.

Comment: What's wrong with the wording you have?

Comment: If you're concerned that *few better ways* is a cliché, please update your question ...

Answer (score 1):

**A not unpleasant way** to ring in the New Year is with a bigger monthly budget.

It sounds like you are looking for a *mild* superlative, i.e. something short of *the best.*   Fortunately, English has quite a few of these little expressions. However, since they are commonplace, most readers expect them to be followed by something *not* commonplace.  Personally, I think your *bigger monthy budget* falls into that category, so you're blessed with a rather large choice.

Answer (score -2):

I would change "better" from an adjective to an adverb, yielding:

> There are few ways better to ring in the new year...

or simply moving it:

> There are few ways to ring in the new year better than...

Actually, "There aren't many ways better to ring in the new year..." sounds less clumsy to me.

Comment: The phrasing *there are few better ways* is extremely idiomatic, and any rephrasing of it sounds clumsy.

Comment: I assumed the OP found "few better" to be less than ideal style; I happen to agree. You apparently do not.

Comment: But your examples change the meaning of the sentence and move the "better" from the "ways" to the "ringing in". Different thing!

Comment: Any difference in meaning is miniscule. A better way to do it and a way to do it better may have different grammar but identical results.